# android - how to create footer banners like admob

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to add my custom  banners and gif animations in some of my activities like the way admob did .

I was wondering how can I do some thing like admob but put my own banners ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a fragment and attach it to the bottom of the activity in which you want to display the ads. You will have to put an ImageView/TextView inside the fragment and do the other necessary things, like downloading the Image from the server...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **LinearLayout** to the activity's xml layout and place it at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Add this container layout to the bottom of the screen -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_container"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And set up the custom gif image to the adView like the following way..

```
public void initAdView() {
        LinearLayout adViewContainer = findViewById(R.id.ad_container);
        ImageView adView = new ImageView(activity);
        adViewContainer.addView(adView);

        //make other thing to set the gif image to the imageView.
        adView.setImageDrawable(gifImage);
    }
```